# duplicate typedef error

Tags: c, typedef, priority-queue

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PRIQUE_H
#define PRIQUE_H

typedef struct queue_node
{
    int val;
    int priority;
    struct queue_node *link;
}

typedef struct p_queue
{
    int size;
    queue_node *first;
}
```

This is my code for header file. When I am running the main program, I am getting error of duplicate typedef. How to fix it. Initially, I had included all the code in a single file but expecting making a header file would fix the issue I made this and the respective definition file. Please tell me where I am wrong and why is this issue occurring?

Comment: WTB some closing type names and semicolons;

Comment: You forgot the `#endif`.

Comment: `typedef struct queue_node {...} queue_node;`.

Answer (score 6):

Making up for my smartass comment, you're missing the closing definition of your typedefs. I.e. you are `typedef`ing something to... nothing. I believe you're trying to do this:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PRIQUE_H
#define PRIQUE_H

typedef struct queue_node
{
    int val;
    int priority;
    struct queue_node *link;
} queue_node;

typedef struct p_queue
{
    int size;
    queue_node *first;
} p_queue;

#endif
```